# Using pattern "Repository" for table relations

Tags: java, database, repository-pattern

Have read about "Repository pattern", before it, I have used pattern DAO (data-acess-object).

How should I implement table relations with this pattern? Should I create entity for links between tables?

Thank you!

Comment: This question come across as, I didn't read this article, can you read it for me? Consider rewriting your question with more context and some actual questions, i.e. Here is how i tried to implement this, but i can't figure out how to do X. As written no one will be able to help you without a lot of assumptions, or guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a one-to-many relationship from a repository, write a class that embodies that relationship, and return it from one of your repository methods.

```
public class Person
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public List<Addresses> addresses
}
```